# matplotlib broken tool chain error

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to install matplotlib using `pip install matplotlib` using Python version 2.7. pip is updated to latest version.

The following is the error:

```
File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 669, in get_mathlib_info
    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Make sure you have `numpy` installed and working first (the error seems to indicate that you do not).

Comment: Looking into numpy github I see that you have some older version of numpy. Try this `pip install numpy --upgrade` then try to install matplotlib one more time.

Comment: I donot have a numpy installed previously.The same error appears when i try to install numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Cross check whether below dependencies installed before installing matploitlib.

- numpy 1.6 (or later)
- setuptools
- dateutil 1.1 or later
- pyparsing
- libpng 1.2 (or later)
- pytz
- freetype 2.3 or later
- cycler 0.9 or later

you can verify by importing the respective module in python environment

*eg:*import numpy

Comment: Hi Kishore, I have installed all these packages except dateutil,libpng.I tried to install them using pip .But I faced an error "couldnot find a version that satisfies the requirement".can u pls help me out